# Automated Build Server and Installing and Executing on Remote machine

Tags: automation, hudson, client-server, jenkins

I am currently working on a test automation system and have a Jenkins (Hudson) Buildserver.
Here I can build my installer and will obtain an executable installer as *.exe.

This *.exe I can put automatically on a networkshare, which can be accessed by all connected computers.

Now I would like to do the following after building the installer.
I would like to deploy it to a computer I can choose within the network and run the program.

I am searching for a solution which best can be integrated within Jenkins, but anyways I can run any programmes on my Jenkins Server from batch.

So what parts would I need and how would you suggest me to implement it?
Of course it the solution should be extensible in future and more communication between Jenkins and the other PCs might be needed.

I guess the main questions are:

How do I best install remote? 
Should I use some sort of Client Server architecture here or what is the best approach?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most installers provide a 'headless' mode of installation for access through scripting. If your installer does, it should be fairly easy to automate it.

Comment: The installers are from myself. I am not quite sure, what this headless mode is about?

Comment: Headless mode means that it runs without a GUI, all parameters which you could specify via the usual GUI (install directory, which sub features to install, ...) are passed via command line or a configuration file, so no GUI interaction is required to run the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is this: run Jenkins [distributively](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) with various machines on which you'd like to run your installer running as slaves. You then write two jobs: *BUILDIT* and *RUNIT*. The first will build your project (it may be tied to only one machine, or to various slaves), the second will run the installer and test the installation (this job will run on slaves on which you want to test).

Now there are two possibilities as to which job to make upstream and which downstream.

(1) *BUILDIT* is upstream. At the end of the build it will call *RUNIT* via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) passing to it the location of the installer. You can either put the installer on a shared drive in a directory keyed by *BULDIT*'s BUILD_ID via [ArtifactDeployer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin) (this is probably the option easiest to implement, but not generic); or *RUNIT* can access the installer artifact via its permalink with wget or curl (in such a case *BUILDIT* would construct and pass to *RUNIT* the link).  There are other options (such as employing [Jenkins Python Remote Access API](http://packages.python.org/jenkinsapi/#)), but they are more difficult to implement.

Now, *RUNIT* can be either a multi-configuration job which will trigger installation/test on all the slaves; or, alternatively, you can pass a parameter from *BUILDIT* specifying on which slave to run. Then, employing [NodeLabel Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) you can tie *RUNIT* to the slave specified by the parameter.

(2) *RUNIT* is upstream. You somehow decide on which slave you want to run your tests and invoke *RUNIT* on that slave (see above on how you can parameterize the slave to run on). *RUNIT* will then invoke *BUILDIT* via *Parameterized Trigger Plugin* run as a build step (not as a post-build step). *RUNIT* should pass to *BUILDIT* its BUILD_ID as a parameter, so that *BUILDIT* can store the installer artifact keyed by it. *RUNIT* will wait for *BUILDIT* to complete, find the installer using the BUILD_ID, and proceed with installation and testing.

Comment: Very comprehensive. I liked the first option - think it is more intuitive.

Comment: I also really like this answer. It is very interesting and I will try it out. Also thanks for the useful plugin references!

Comment: Why is the ArtifactDeployer plugin not generic or what exactly is meant by that. Sorry for being not sure about it.

Comment: @Byron-LimTimothySteffan, the approach is not generic enough, the plugin is fine. Consider: you may not have a file server; some of the slaves may be behind a firewall; if the files erver is not under your control you are dependent on IT - they can bring it down for maintenance, or change it's name or directory structure. Don't take me wrong - it's not a bad approach, otherwise I'd not suggest it :). If you go this way - make sure that you define the server name and path as Jenkins-wide environment variables. Then you'll have only one point of change in case you need to modify them.